# How to know the existence of replica set in sharded environment from JAVA client

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java

I want to set

```
mongoClient.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.REPLICAS_SAFE);
```

only if replica set is present.

But in sharded environment when I do:

```
mongoClient.getReplicaSetStatus();
```

It returns null even though I have replica set.

To mongo client I am passing mongos IP.

Comment: You could use replica:"majority" - replica_safe means w:2, but majority is calculated based on number of nodes in a replica set, so if you have one, then majority is also 1.  Just knowing you are talking to a replica set isn't enough as technically you can have a replica set of one member configured.

Comment: just confirmed, with no replica set, w:2 gives an error but w:"majority" gives success on write to one.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I want to give different option to the user,based on their demand,now if the user set REPLICA_SAFE and their is no,replica set it goes to dead lock,so I want to test before setting.

Comment: If you've already gone to deadlock maybe you should try restarting your replica set and trying the code again?

Comment: @omalsa04 I think you're confused about that comment - there is no deadlock on the replica set, there is a wait (forever) on the client side for non-existent replica to acknowledge.  Except that there isn't, if there is no replica and you send w:2 (replica_safe) then you get an error {
 "n" : 0,
 "connectionId" : 15,
 "wnote" : "no replication has been enabled, so w=2.0 won't work",
 "err" : "norepl",
 "ok" : 1
}

Answer (score 1):

Most MongoDB drivers, in particular Java driver which you are using will throw an exception if you try to set REPLICA_ACKNOWLEDGED writeConcern when it's not possible to get an acknowledgement from two or more nodes.

From the docs:

```
WriteConcern.REPLICA_ACKNOWLEDGED          Tries to write to two separate nodes. [...] will
                                           throw an exception if two writes are not possible.
```

See the following for more details:

- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/write-concern/
- http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-replica-set-semantics/

In my testing with mongo shell, if you provide REPLICA_ACKNOWLEDGED (formerly called REPLICA_SAFE) concern to 'getlasterror' command, you will get an error when you are not communicating with a replica set.  When talking to `mongos` process, the error will be:

```
{
    "singleShard" : "localhost:30001",
    "n" : 0,
    "connectionId" : 3,
    "wnote" : "no replication has been enabled, so w=2.0 won't work",
    "err" : "norepl",
    "ok" : 1
}
```

It is not the case that the client will hang forever without `wtimeout` being specified, that would only be the case if there is a replica set but two nodes are not available for writes indefinitely.

Note that using "majority" as `w` value for write concern **will** work correctly through `mongos` - note the difference in writeConcern responses:

```
mongos> db.coll.insert({}); db.runCommand({getlasterror:1,w:"majority"})
{
    "singleShard" : "localhost:30001",
    "n" : 0,
    "connectionId" : 3,
    "err" : null,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First verify that your replica set has a PRIMARY using the mongo shell command `rs.status()`

Then if that worked, verify that you are connecting to the database correctly:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "hostname" , 27017 );
```

If both of those are true then there should be no reason `mongoClient.getReplicaSetStatus()` should return NULL. It should be returning a [ReplicaSetStatus](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.11.1/com/mongodb/ReplicaSetStatus.html) object.